# Amazon Spectrum incremental load directly from string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have take a field as 'filename Pro_180913_171842' from spectrum.
Tried the function in sql like

```
       `select
       fields
      from spectrum.ex
      where cast(SPLIT_PART('filename Pro_180913_171842','Pro_',2)as 
      timestamp)>cast('2018-09-12 15:13:54.0' as timestamp)`
```

but it returned empty rows only!

Comment: To what do the values `180913` and `171842` correspond?

Comment: It is timestamp like '2018-09-13 17:18:42.0'.Able to take as field but incremental load is not working.

Comment: You are trying to compare a time, with no date component, against a timestamp, which has a date component.  What is your logic here?

Answer (score 0):

Your field has no date component, so unless we add date information, it makes no sense to compare to a full timestamp.  If you intend to compare only times, then try this:

```
SELECT fields
FROM spectrum.ex
WHERE SPLIT_PART('filename Pro_180913_171842', '_', 2) > '151354';
```